# Android Html.fromHtml function auto converts undesired text into hyperlinks

Tags: android, html, textview

Android Html.fromHtml function auto converts undesired text into hyperlinks.

Here is my code:

```
 String htmlContent= "corners of nail.It has to";
 textViewContent.setTextHtml.fromHtml(htmlContent));
 textViewContent.setText(comment.getContent());
```

In above code Html.fromHtml treats "nails.It" as a link and converts it into hyperlink.

Here is the result of converted string.
[image]

One of the solution which I could think is, put space after fullstop.
Is there any good solution?

Comment: did you tried the html representation of dot: &sdot;

Comment: You should probably remove android:autoLink="web" from your xml layout for textViewContent. It's not really useful if you expecting text like you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this.

```
  textViewContent.setText( Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"YOURDESIREDLINK.COM\">YOUR DESIRED TEXT</a>"));
  textViewContent. setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Provide space between dot and second statement

```
     String htmlContent= "corners of nail. It has to";
     textViewContent.setTextHtml.fromHtml(htmlContent));
     textViewContent.setText(comment.getContent());
```